# Heading inside paragraph selector not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to change the background color of all the children of the `<p>` tag to GREEN. But the code I have written doesn't work. But if I change the `<p>` tag to `<div>` it's working. But I need it to work on the `<p>` tag using jQuery Advanced Selectors

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  //Change background color of children to green
  //Below code is not working
  $("#intro").children().each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
  });
  //Show only first 2 list item
  $('ol li').hide().slice(0, 2).show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="intro">jQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more" JavaScript library.
  <h6>The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website</h6>
</p>
<ol>
  <li>HTML/DOM manipulation</li>
  <li>CSS manipulation</li>
  <li>Effects and animations</li>
  <li>AJAX</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h` is not a valid child of `p`

[Paragraph P](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p)

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag.

Permitted content: [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)

The rendered HTML becomes

```html
<p id="intro">jQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more" JavaScript library.
</p><!-- inserted by browser -->
<h6>The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website</h6>
<p><!-- inserted by browser -->
</p>
```

You can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  //Change background color of children to green
  //Below code is now working
  $("#intro").children().each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    $('<br />').insertBefore(this); // because of the inline-block
  });
  //Show only first 2 list item
  $('ol li').hide().slice(0, 2).show();
})
```

```css
.h6 { 
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: .67em;
    margin-top: 2.33em;
    margin-bottom: 2.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="intro">jQuery is a lightweight, "write less, do more" JavaScript library.
  <span class="h6">The purpose of jQuery is to make it much easier to use JavaScript on your website</span>
</p>
<ol>
  <li>HTML/DOM manipulation</li>
  <li>CSS manipulation</li>
  <li>Effects and animations</li>
  <li>AJAX</li>
</ol>
```